# OSError: [Errno 98] Address already in useがでて先に進めません。

Tags: heroku, flask

[Heroku初心者がFlaskを使った簡素なアプリケーションをデプロイするまで！ - Qiita](https://qiita.com/Rowing0914/items/de16bc2676705bd94d24)

上記のページを参考にして、flaskで作った簡単なアプリをherokuでデプロイしようとしています。
しかし、`$ heroku open`したあとにApplicationエラーが発生し、詰まってしまっています。

コンソールで以下のエラーが確認できました。

```
$ heroku logs --tail
OSError: [Errno 98] Address already in use
```

試したこと
・パソコンの再起動
・app.run(port=5000)のポート番号を変えた
・killコマンド周辺は理解できませんでした。

必要な情報や補足などあれば随時確認、追記します。
3/20までに公開したいアプリですのでどうぞ知恵をお貸しください、よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

Herokuのサーバで別のflaskのプログラムが起動中(5000番ポートを使用中）なのだと思われますから、そのプログラムを停止することで問題解決するはずです。
そのプログラムはHerokuのサーバで動いているので、自分のパソコンを再起動してもダメなんです。

Qiitaの　[Herokuのアプリケーションの停止 / 再開](https://qiita.com/akiko-pusu/items/dec93cca4855e811ba6c)　という記事にHerokuで動いているプログラムを停止する方法が説明されています。